# NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I'm trying to incorporate images into my web app and I keep running into this error after removing quite a few features. It came down to my 'create' application controller and I'm not entirely sure where I should go from here.

```
2015-02-06T20:30:12.292187+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-02-06T20:30:12.296299+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):
2015-02-06T20:30:12.296301+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:24:in `create'
2015-02-06T20:45:14.691084+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving /articles/images/000/000/013/original/git.jpeg
2015-02-06T20:45:14.698744+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 584ms
2015-02-06T20:45:14.700871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=preston.herokuapp.com request_id=d9d02257-3616-4686-bce5-3d912cd528c2 fwd="76.22.102.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=698ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password", except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end 

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
          redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end  
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private

    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image)
    end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3' 
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0.22'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'byebug'
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', require: false
end
```

Comment: Are you deploying to Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I already have and I'm looking in the heroku logs and found that error.

Comment: it's most likely because you didn't initialize the AWS constants in Heroku, you need to run  $ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key

Comment: hmmm I did follow that step but I'll start all over just to make sure it's right

Comment: Ok let me know if it works so that I can make it an answer for other people to benefit as well.

Comment: I'm still receiving the same errors as before.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Modify your Gemfile's aws-sdk to install a version prior to 2.0:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

This issue was introduced with new version of aws-sdk (2.0+). You can read more here: http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2

Comment: I've found that the reason is in updated 'aws-sdk' gem. There is a new version (2+) of aws-sdk that is not backward compatible with previous versions. You can read a bit more [here:](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#nameerror-uninitialized-constant-aws)

Comment: Also, you can replace that line with `gem 'aws-sdk-v1'`. This then allows you to pull in the v2 aws-sdk gem. They can be used together in the same application because of the different namespaces.

Comment: Trevor Rowe's solution worked perfectly for me -- and the fact that they can be used simultaneously is very useful. Thanks Trevor!

Answer (score 18):

There is official solution
Use paperclip from this branch:
it works with aws-sdk versions above 2

```
gem 'paperclip', :git=> 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip', :ref => '523bd46c768226893f23889079a7aa9c73b57d68'
```

just add :s3_region parameter to your paperclip s3 config

works for me

Comment: This is the best answer now, as aws 1 is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by navigating to my gem folder and changing the Gems to:

- gem ‘paperclip’
- gem ‘aws-sdk’

The version declarations can be dropped.

To avoid getting a `gem.lock error`, run `bundle update` instead of `bundle install`, otherwise only the gems will be updated.

Now, the `heroku logs -t` command can be used to monitor the heroku server to image uploads.

I orginally received a new error, `Access Denied Error` for AWS server.

To fix this I found the `Active Access Key ID` with the latest date on the Amazon websiteand used heroku commands to input the latest `Access key ID` and `Secret access key`.

This enabled me to view my image on heroku.

I had made so many `Access key ID` and `Secret access keys` trying to fix the problem, but found the Gems to be the real problem.

Tip: Save all your Access Key info to OneNote, Notepad, etc. This way you can return and check them.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you resolve it by removing the versions?

Answer (score 3):

Paperclip use to use AWS-SDK v1 in versions 4.3 and bellow. They are trying to include the AWS-SDK v2

official upgrade document https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/UPGRADING

```
##################################################
#  NOTE FOR UPGRADING FROM 4.3.0 OR EARLIER       #
##################################################

Paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0.

If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few small
changes:

* You must set the `s3_region`
* If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an initializer,
  note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore to
  using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
  `public-read`.
```

due to some backwards incomparability (read this https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2021) this is merged but officially not released yet, but should be released in Paperclip v `5.0.0`

So like [Vitali Mogilevsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262467/473040) mentioned, you have to use this for now:

```
# Gemfile
# ...
gem 'paperclip', :git=> 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip', :ref => '523bd46c768226893f23889079a7aa9c73b57d68'
```

When Paperclip 5.0 is released, AWS-SDK v2  should be included