# Facing issue uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Errors in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

to upload images or any other document. I have these two models: 
employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

and in attachment.rb

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :attach,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => '#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml',
                    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
                    :path => '/contents/:id/:basename.:extension'
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach,:content_type => ['application/msword','application/pdf', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
end
```

and in my employeeS_controller.rb

```
 def edit
    @employee = Employee.where(id: params[:id]).first
    @employee.attachments.build
  end

  def update
    @employee = Employee.where(id: params[:id]).first
    if @employee.update_attributes(employee_params)
      redirect_to @employee, notice: I18n.t('employee_updated')
    else
      p @employee.errors
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end


  private

  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:email, :role, :department_id, :designation_id, :is_active, attachments_attributes: [:attach, :name])
  end
```

and in my employess/edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attach|%>
              <%= attach.file_field :attach, :class => 'btn' %>
 <% end %>
```

Now when am submitting the form am getting this in my params

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"4pq1y2qS0AAbO+C6O1Sp0qmKFFXG2KZtB4mvIgvK3CKJ0CI/5yAYDJArhjsEzu6lSm/LkRfBIJDpSzRZUxp+bQ==",
>   "employee"=>{"email"=>"inventory@adroit.com", "role"=>"INVENTORY",
>   "department_id"=>"6", "designation_id"=>"3", "is_active"=>"1",
>   "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"attach"=>#,
>   @original_filename="index.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"employee[attachments_attributes][0][attach]\";
>   filename=\"index.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}},
>   "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"employees", "id"=>"3"}

But its not saving in my database it gives me error NameError **(uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Errors):**

and my settings in s3.yml is

```
development:
  bucket: "test"
  access_key_id: "*************"
  secret_access_key: "*************"

production:
  bucket: "test"
  access_key_id: "*************"
  secret_access_key: "*************"
```

when I had don `bundle show aws-sdk` then I have this version of aws-sdk bundle show aws-sdk

```
/home/test/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-2.0.46
```

Now please guide where am missing I am not getting it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: might will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws

Comment: Yeah i have restarted the server too. But still facing issue