# How to setup Amazon S3 with Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, spree

I have tried reading a lot of things online, none of them helped. So need a concrete answer. How do I configure S3 to work with Spree?
I am using Spree 3.0.1 with Rails 4.2.1.

I have spree.rb as:

```
Spree.config do |config|
   # Example:
   # Uncomment to override the default site name.
  #  config.site_name = "Gazella Running Costumes"
  #  config.logo = "store/rungazella.png"

  #S3 configuration
  if Rails.env.production? then
       #production. Store images on S3.
       # development will default to local storage
      attachment_config = {
      s3_credentials: {
        access_key_id: ENV["S3_KEY"],
        secret_access_key: ENV["S3_SECRET"],
        bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET"],
      },


      storage:        :s3,
      s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
      s3_protocol:    "https",
      bucket:         ENV["S3_BUCKET"],

      path:          ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      default_url:   "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      default_style: "product",
      }

      attachment_config.each do |key, value|
           Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
      end
  end
Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
end
```

Also my Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'spring'
end
gem 'spree', '3.0.1'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Comment: Are you using the paperclip gem to handle images?

Comment: Yes I am using paperclip.

Comment: Did you come with a solution? I'm struggling with this myself, and can't get it to work

Comment: In the project I'm working on, I found that S3 wasn't working because `Spree::Image` was reopened, and `path` and `url` options were set there too, which won over those settings in the initializer. Also, as of Spree 3.0.2, `aws-sdk` must be `< 2.0`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing `path` from the settings:

`path: ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",`

It seems odd to have a `path` that references your Rails root when the image will be stored in S3.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the gem 'aws-sdk' with version less than 2.0:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

then, you need to add this code in the spree initializer:

```
Rails.env.production?
  attachment_config = {
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      bucket:            ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
    },

    storage:        :s3,
    s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
    s3_protocol:    "https",
    bucket:         ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    url:            ":s3_domain_url",

    path:           "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_url:    "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_style:  "product"
  }

  attachment_config.each do |key, value|
    Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem

```
 gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

Use this snippet in config/initializers/spree.rb

```
spree.config do |config|
  attachment_config={
  s3_credentials: {
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  bucket: ENV['ENV_BUCKET_NAME']
  },
  storage:     :s3,
  s3_headers:  {"Cache-Control"=>"max-age=31557600"},
  s3_protocol: "https",
  bucket:      ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  url:         "url",
  styles:      {
                 mini:   "48x48>",
                 small:  "100x100>",
                 product:"240x240>",
                 large:  "600x600>"
               },
  path:        "/spree/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_url: "/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_style: "product",
  }
  attachment_config.each do |key,value|

   Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value

  end

end
```

[source](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/s3_storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

First Remove your S3 configuration settings from your `spree.rb` Spree backend already have this configuration in `General Settings => image settings => enable S3`.

Hey you just need to enable the S3 from you spree backend. Provide the basic details required over there.
Add a following line in you initilizer `paperclip.rb`

```
if Rails.env.production?
    Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) do |attachment, style|
      "#{attachment.s3_protocol}://#{Spree::Config[:s3_host_alias]}/#{attachment.bucket_name}/#{attachment.path(style).gsub(%r{^/}, "")}"
    end
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = "https"
end
```

Your attachment Url should be `:s3_eu_url` as we initialized the interpolation for this URL in initilizer

Comment: But I cannot find it under spree 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: [NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws)

Change your gemfile `aws-sdk` gem to:
`gem aws-sdk, < 2.0`

Apparantly the issue starts with a newer version of `aws-sdk` so you need a version that's lower than 2.0.