# Paperclip NameError (uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Errors) in Rails 4 on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

When I upload an image using paperclip and s3 storage. The app works fine locally, I've made the required changes to use s3 for `heroku`, but on heroku the issue remains continues:

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.5.3"
```

store.rb

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo,
  styles: {
  thumb: ["40x40#", :png],
  small: ["400x400>", :png]},
  default_url: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/missing.jpg",
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  path: "/store_logos/:style/:id/:filename"
end
```

config/s3.yml

```
development:
  bucket: app-dev
  access_key_id: ***********
  secret_access_key: ***************
production:
  bucket: app-pro
  access_key_id: ***********
  secret_access_key: ***************
```

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws#answer-28376678) but no luck.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you setting the bucket ? I can't see where it's being set

Comment: @Kiloreux in `config/s3.yml` I added the bucket credentials

Comment: If you are using the AWS SDK, why do you load the AWS S3 gem?  Not sure it should matter, but I would only load what you are using.  And of course make sure you restart Rails.  Otherwise, can you include the full stack trace in your post?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace for the error

Comment: Linking this topic with related topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution to the issue. Updated the `Gemfile` and `models/store.rb`.

Reference document [here](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2)

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

models/store.rb

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'aws-sdk-v1'
  require 'aws-sdk'
  has_attached_file :logo,
  styles: {
    thumb: ["40x40#", :png],
    small: ["400x400>", :png]},
    default_url: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/missing.jpg",
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    path: "/store_logos/:style/:id/:filename"
end
```

Comment: Is that the best place to put the `require aws-sdd-v1` code?